# jQuery: set selected value of dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with this code?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#routetype").val('quietest');
)};
```

HTML

```
<select id="routetype" name="routetype">
    <option value="fastest">Fastest</option>
    <option selected="true" value="balanced">Balanced</option>
    <option value="quietest">Quietest</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3UyB/1/)

It gives me 'Balanced' as the selected option, not 'Quietest'.

Comment: You need to select jQuery in the dropdown on the left and you have a syntax error because the `$(document).ready` should end with `});` not `)};`  See: http://jsfiddle.net/x3UyB/2/

Comment: @mVChr you should post that as an answer =)

Comment: @mVChr thank you, please post as an answer :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to select jQuery in the dropdown on the left and you have a syntax error because the `$(document).ready` should end with `});` not `)};` [Check this link.](http://jsfiddle.net/x3UyB/2)

Comment: Thanks. Actually the issue was because I was working with jQuery Mobile and you need to call `$("#routetype").selectmenu('refresh');` as well to update what is shown.

Answer (score 68):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Old answer, correct method nowadays is to use jQuery's `.prop()`. IE, `element.prop("selected", true)`

**OLD ANSWER:**

Use this instead:

```
$("#routetype option[value='quietest']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

**Fiddle'd:** http://jsfiddle.net/x3UyB/4/

Comment: what if I want to use a variable instead of a hard-coded value (like "quietest"?

Comment: @Kevin You can always do `$("#routetype option").each()` to compare dropdown values, or just `$("#routetype option[value='"+option_value+"']");`

Comment: @mattsven, I get selected='selected' on two options this way. just an FYI.

Answer (score 4):

You can select dropdown option value by name

```
jQuery("#option_id").find("option:contains('Monday')").each(function()
{
 if( jQuery(this).text() == 'Monday' )
 {
  jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
  }
});
```