# how to make a value of dropdown selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

how to make an index selected and show in dropdown list i want to make 2nd index selected and show in dropdown how i do this? 
here is my code:

```
{% for items in itemdata %}
 {{items.invoiceitemsid}}
 {% if items.invoiceitemsid =='2' %}
        $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
        $('.items').append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
        $('.items').append("<option value='2'>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
        $('.items').append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
        $(".items option[value='2']").prop('selected', true);
 {% elseif items.invoiceitemsid =='3' %}
        $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
        $('.items').append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
        $('.items').append("<option value='2'>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
        $('.items').append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
        $(".items option[value='3']").prop('selected', true);
{% else %}
        $('.items').find('option').remove().end();
        $('.items').append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
        $('.items').append("<option value='2'>{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
        $('.items').append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
        $(".items option[value='1']").prop('selected', true);
{% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

and here is my html code:

```
<select class="items" name="items{{loop.index0}}" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items{{loop.index0}}"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
```

i want to show the selected option in this combo box,my itemsdata has an array of numbers,like 1,2,3 if items.invoiceid=1 option value one show and if items.invoiceid=2 option value 2 show as selected

i want to make 2nd index show as selected value how i do this?

Comment: Check that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810016/jquery-set-selected-value-of-dropdown-list

Comment: As a sidenote, `.val()` in the end of each line is redundant, since you already added the attribute in the HTML string inside `append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the `2nd` option (2nd index), you may try this

```
$('.items option:eq(1)').prop('selected', 1);
```

Or try

```
$('.items')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZcBG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If `.items` is your `<select>`:  `$('.items').val('2')` after adding all options.

Otherwise, you can call `.prop('selected', true)` on the `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(".items option[value='2']").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$('.items').find('option').remove().end();
$('.items').append("<option value='1'>{{item1}}</option>").val('1');
$('.items').append("<option value='2' selected="selected">{{item2}}</option>").val('2');
$('.items').append("<option value='3'>{{item3}}</option>").val('3');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.items').append("<option value='1'>item1</option>").val('1');
$('.items').append("<option value='2'>item2</option>").val('2');
$('.items').append("<option value='3'>item3</option>").val('3');

$('select.items>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4EncF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   $('.items').get(0).selectedIndex = 2;
```